# What is the name for the class of computer programs that act as a front end for a database?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology, technical

If you are writing a computer program that manages a large database of clients, like a rolodex, or a program that stores medical records for patients. What is that "class" of program called.

The specific term my company uses for the software it develops is "Practice management software" but I am looking for the next broader up in specificity, as I want to use this word in a non medical software context.

A good example of this type of program would be [Microsoft Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/).

Comment: You'll be more likely to get accurate results at a software site, SO or programmers. This is a local technical question.

Comment: @Mitch Martin hit the nail on the head, I just have to wait the 15 min to accept the answer.

Comment: sure it's a great question and answer, just not appropriate for EL&U.

Comment: actually, is Access a CRUD app? I don't think so. Anyway, this should all be migrated elsewhere.

Comment: @mitch - it's both, it's a database but you can also write client apps in access to access access databases ;-)

Comment: @waiwai933 You migrated my question to programmers but it appears to have been deleted over there (or at least when I [click the link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/112683/what-is-the-name-for-the-class-of-computer-programs-that-act-as-a-front-end-for) it says page not found). Can you either re-open the question here or migrate it again and tell the mods that you feel that it should be over there not here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are normally called [CRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) apps by managers, or [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) apps by programmers.

Comment: CRM was the exact word I was looking for.

Comment: CRM and CRUD are not synonyms at all. I'd expect a programmer to know if the particular CRUD app he was working on was a CRM app or not, and call it CRM if it were.

Comment: That is incorrect. CRM stands for customer relationship management.